# Resample signal at specific time lags

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a 10x1100 matrix, which represents the coefficients of a scalogram for a signal of 1.1sec duration at 1kHz sampling rate. The scalogram has 10 frequencies, so basically the rows of the matrix are the frequency bins and the columns are the time points.

And then I want to resample that matrix to form a 10x10 matrix. To be more specific, what I want to do is the following (part of a paper I'm working on):
"The scalogram was then resampled at 10 time lags (t−100ms, t−200ms,...,and t−1s) to form a 10×10 scalogram matrix of time t."

So, how exactly should I make that resampling? I am aware of the Matlab functions downsample, resample, decimate, but I am not sure about the way I should resample that matrix. Should I just take every 100th element of my initial matrix or should I use the decimate function which also filters the signal? And if not the first case, how can I make Matlab resample at those specific 10 time lags?